# why this session in particular is suspended? Please see the details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

My understanding regarding the suspended status of a session:

> A query gets suspended when it is requesting access to a resource that
>   is currently not available. This can be a logical resource like a
>   locked row or a physical resource like a memory data page. The query
>   starts running again, once the resource becomes available.

But what about the following session?

The session in question is the `number 65`, `in yellow` on the picture below.

How can I check whether the process is actually doing something?

I know that there are many questions about this on the net, but still I could not figure it out when it happens with me.

I have one of my users running the following set of updates:

```
        --------------------------------------------------------------
        -- need to add an update using the SUBS table
        --------------------------------------------------------------

/*      update dbo.FR_20150817 set
             title = s.title
            ,first_name = s.fname
            ,last_name = s.lname
        --  ,subscribe_date = s.subscribe_date
            ,newsletters = '1' -- s.newsletters
            ,style_notes = '1' -- s.style_notes
            ,sale_notifications = '1' -- s.sale_notifications
            ,all_my_offers = '1' -- s.all_my_offers
            ,ratings_and_reviews_invites = '1' -- s.ratings_and_reviews_invites
        from crm_staging.dbo.subs_20131009 s
        where 1 = 1
            and dbo.FR_20150817.email_address = s.email;
*/          

        insert into dbo.FR_20150817(
             email_address
            ,title
            ,first_name
            ,last_name
        --  ,subscribe_date
            ,newsletters
            ,style_notes
            ,sale_notifications
            ,all_my_offers
            ,ratings_and_reviews_invites
        )
        select s.email as 'email_address'
            ,case when len(s.title) = 1 then '' else isnull(s.title,'') end as 'title'
            ,case when len(s.fname) = 1 then '' else isnull(s.fname,'') end as 'first_name'
            ,case when len(s.lname) = 1 then '' else isnull(s.lname,'') end as 'last_name'
        --  ,s.sunscribe_date as 'subscribe_date'
            ,case when dbo.udf_check_empty(newsletters) = 1 then '0' else '1' end as 'newsletters'
            ,case when dbo.udf_check_empty(style_notes) = 1 then '0' else '1' end as 'style_notes'
            ,case when dbo.udf_check_empty(sale_notifications) = 1 then '0' else '1' end as 'sale_notifications'
            ,case when dbo.udf_check_empty(all_my_offers) = 1 then '0' else '1' end as 'all_my_offers'
            ,case when dbo.udf_check_empty(ratings_and_reviews_invites) = 1 then '0' else '1' end as 'ratings_and_reviews_invites'
        from crm_staging.dbo.subs_20131009 s
        where 1 = 1
            and s.aid = 2087301848
            and dbo.udf_reg_exp_match(isnull(s.email,''),N'^[a-zA-ZÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸ¡¿çÇŒœßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-ZÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸ¡¿çÇŒœßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-ZÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸ¡¿çÇŒœßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð]{2,4}$') = 1
            and not exists (
                select d.email_address
                from dbo.FR_20150817 d
                where 1 = 1
                    and d.email_address = s.email
            )
            and not exists (
                select c.stremail
                from crm_staging.dbo.[01customers] c
                where 1 = 1
                    and c.stremail = s.email
            );


        update dbo.FR_20150817 set
             title = d.title
            ,first_name = d.fname
            ,last_name = d.lname
            ,newsletters = replace(replace(d.newsletters,'Y','1'),'N','0')
            ,style_notes = replace(replace(d.style_notes,'Y','1'),'N','0')
            ,sale_notifications = replace(replace(d.sale_notifications,'Y','1'),'N','0')
            ,all_my_offers = replace(replace(d.all_my_offers,'Y','1'),'N','0')
            ,ratings_and_reviews_invites = replace(replace(d.ratings_and_reviews_invites,'Y','1'),'N','0')
        from crm_staging.dbo.demo_20131009 d
        where 1 = 1
            and dbo.FR_20150817.email_address = d.email;

        update dbo.FR_20150817 set
             newsletters = 0
            ,style_notes = 0
            ,sale_notifications = 0
            ,all_my_offers = 0
            ,ratings_and_reviews_invites = 0
        from crm_staging.dbo.data_20131009_50 d
        where 1 = 1
            and dbo.FR_20150817.email_address = d.uid;

        update dbo.FR_20150817 set
             title = d.title
            ,first_name = d.fname
            ,last_name = d.lname
            ,newsletters = 0
            ,style_notes = 0
            ,sale_notifications = 0
            ,all_my_offers = 0
            ,ratings_and_reviews_invites = 0
        from crm_staging.dbo.unsubs_20131009 d
        where 1 = 1
            and dbo.FR_20150817.email_address = d.email;
```

Using the sp_whoisactive, that you can download [here](http://whoisactive.com), I get the following picture:

[image]

Let me add that:

1) There is enough space in the log file

2) There is enough space in the disk

3) There are no locks and blocks

4) Tempdb is a variable - yes

5) In theory I have enough memory for all these updates

6) CPU should be fine - so I believe

**Assing the current waits stats** - I have not been monitoring them, but just adding it here for information

This is the query I used to collect them:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
        N'CLR_SEMAPHORE',    N'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP',
        N'RESOURCE_QUEUE',   N'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH',
        N'SLEEP_TASK',       N'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK',
        N'WAITFOR',          N'HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION',
        N'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', N'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH',
        N'XE_TIMER_EVENT',   N'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN',
        N'LOGMGR_QUEUE',     N'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TASK_STOP', N'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT',
        N'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',   N'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE',
        N'TRACEWRITE',       N'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TO_FLUSH',  N'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER',
        N'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX',  N'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP',
        N'DIRTY_PAGE_POLL',  N'SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP')
order by wait_time_ms desc;
```

[image]

Comment: The wait type is as such not of much worry but you should worry how much time this wait type is there. If it is there for longer period of duration then you need to take steps given in answer. What is condition with you ?

Comment: there is not monitoring strategy on this server at the moment, but this example shows the importance of having one

Comment: I am asking does this wait type stays there for long ? Does this wait type also appears as prominent one in wait type when you query `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`

Comment: @Shanky that was a one-off bunch of queries that are run 3-4 times a year, so as I mentioned, I have not put anything in place to monitor these waits on this server, so I don't know. for your information, I use this link to monitor waits, I find it very useful http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: @Shanky I have edited the question to add this information for you. I got the query from another link that I like: http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/

Comment: You have CXPACKET waits followed by Async_IO, PAGEIOLATCH*,BACKUPIO. Actually if you really want to capture wait stats first clear it and leave system for 1 or 2 days and then run the query again. Make sure for these 1 or 2 days you heavily use the system. As of now *it seems* your storage is slow and that might be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I check whether the process is actually doing something?

For the session 65, process is suspended because its waiting on a process to complete. That wait info itself is highlighted there as PAGEIOLATCH_SH..

This means from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984(v=sql.110).aspx)

> Occurs when a task is waiting on a latch for a buffer that is not in
>   an I/O request. The latch request is in Shared mode.

These waits are commonly associated with disk I/O bottlenecks, though the root
cause of the problem may be, and commonly is, a poorly performing query that is
consuming excessive amounts of memory in the server. PAGEIOLATCH_* waits are
specifically associated with delays in being able to read or write data from the database
files.

The first thing you need to analyse is how frequent is this wait. Compare this with you're baseline data and see if its actually a problem.

May be it comes for a fraction of second and then just vanishes. Should not be that big a concern for you in case you saying its not blocking. But again it depends how you have baseline the data.

Referring from this very helpful article [Knee-Jerk Wait Statistics : PAGEIOLATCH_SH](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/io-subsystem/knee-jerk-waits-pageiolatch-sh)

> Here are some possible root causes (not an exhaustive list):
>
> - External Windows memory pressure on SQL Server causing the memory    manager to reduce the buffer pool size
> - Plan cache bloat causing extra memory to be borrowed from the buffer     pool
> - A query plan doing a table/clustered index scan (instead of an index     seek) because of:
>
>   1. a workload volume increase
>   2. a parameter sniffing
>   3. problem a required nonclustered index that was dropped or changed
>   4. An implicit conversion